# What kind of screw is this? It's meant to be paired with a grommet

Tags: screws

What kind of screw is this? And what characteristics are relevant when trying to locate a suitable replacement?

It's meant to be paired with a grommet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the results of a search for "disk drive isolation screw" match what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

This is referred to as a "shoulder screw" because the wide section above the threads stops it from going in any further.  They can be used so that soft or brittle materials like plastic of a certain thickness are held in place without being pinched or over-tightened.

I've also seen these used as a type of "standoff" that you could hook a spring or cable onto, but the basic term "shoulder screw" is what will help the most.

Answer (score 3):

I would call that a Phillips head shoulder machine screw but the thread pitch and size would be needed. I did find one site that called them stepped bolt Phillips. 
The head type , shoulder length and diameter then the thread size pitch and length are all needed to get an exact name.